# Update the path column in MySQL database for specific records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a column in MySQL database that store the images names/IDs something like "523523525.jpg".

I want to update this column by adding the folder before the image name/ID to be like "101/523523525.jpg". I want to update specific records not all the column, for example update from record 1 to 1000 by adding "101/...." and records from 1001 to 2000 by adding "102/....".

Look for your ideas.

Comment: Do you have an auto incremented id columun on the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an id column.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD 
COLUMN id INT AUTO_INCREMENT 
PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

use concat to update rows based on id

```
UPDATE your_table SET 
Column=CONCAT("101/",column) 
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

for first 1 to 1000 to use LIMIT in update statement.
For next 1001-2000 you need to write anonymous block or procedure using cursor to update records.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the CONCAT function? Assuming you have a seperate column for the id, you can execute an update query to add the path to the existing value.

```
UPDATE your_table SET path_col=CONCAT('101/', path_col) WHERE id between 1 AND 1000;
```

Hope it helps! Feel free to ask if you need to know anything.